# How to say "Getting/experiencing through different situations"?

Tags: translation

I am writing about the language and I wish to say, that the language can be learnt best, when you can visit it's country, so you could master it by:

> "getting through different situations" or "experiencing through different situations"

I came up with 「**様々な【さまざまな】状況【じょうきょう】を通して【とおして】経験【けいけん】すること**」, but I think there are much more natural ways of expressing this idea. Also, I am not sure, if the word 状況【じょうきょう】as for "situation" fits well here...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is good, but it can be improved a bit more.

As 「[経験]{けいけん}する」 is a transitive verb, it's a little bit strange it doesn't have an object.

You can say 「[経験]{けいけん}を[積]{つ}む」 to mean "gain experience" without mentioning what kind of experience they have.
The resulting sentence 「**[様々]{さまざま}な[状況]{じょうきょう}を[通]{とお}して[経験]{けいけん}を[積]{つ}むこと**」 seems no problem to me.

Another option is to say 「[様々]{さまざま}な[状況]{じょうきょう}を[経験]{けいけん}すること」 which literally means "to experience different situations."

---

Lastly, your word choice of 「[状況]{じょうきょう}」 is very good.
Also, 「[場面]{ばめん}」 is acceptable here.

Answer (score 6):

> 「場数{ばかず}を踏{ふ}む」

is the first expression that came to mind.

「様々な状況を通して経験する」 is grammatical and it makes perfect sense, but it is wordy and it sounds as if it were directly translated.